# Javascript, submit button not calling function in HTML5 page

Tags: javascript, html

This is for a homework assignment... The page is definitely incomplete, but i should still be able to call my function with the submit button, correct?

I keep receiving errors the file cannot be found, OR the form will not process.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Example</title> 
         <script type="text/javascript">
         function f1(){
            document.writeln("Hello"); 
            };
        </script>  
    </head> 
    <body>

        <form>
            Customer Name: <input type = "text" id = "cusName"/>
             </p>
         Delivery Date: <input type = "text" id="delDate"/>
             </p>
         Number of items: <input type = "text" id = "numItem"/>
            </p>
       <button onlick="f1();return false">Submit</button>
         </form>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo here in your button you typed "`onlick`" instead of `onClick`

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what it is.

It's amazing what a 2nd set of eyes will do.

Comment: Happy it helped , please accept my answer as the right answer so others can know it worked for you